# Accessing .properties property

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to CodenameOne, great platform.

I see a file called "codenameone_settings.properties"  I added a new property called "myapi", "http://localhost:3000"

How would I access this property?  I tried

```
Preferences.set("myapi", "nono")
```

When I do:

```
System.out.println(Preferences.set("myapi", "nono"));
```

I get "nono"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "codenameone_settings.properties" is a project configuration file which is not accessible to the app.
If you need/want a properties file to be used in your app add your own properties file to the project src/ folder and load it from code.

For example:

```
   //place the App_settings.properties under the src/ dir
    Properties conf = new Properties();
    conf.load(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/App_settings.properties"));
```